# IOS webview not show system alert like "the request time out"

Tags: ios, webview

My app is a web view app, but it shows a system alert like "the request time out". I do not want to show this alert.

Can I dismiss this alert? Or how can I click the OK button in the source. Or can I get the OK object? So I can do click event in source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IOS7
Class UIAlertManager = objc_getClass("_UIAlertManager");
UIAlertView *topMostAlert = [UIAlertManager performSelector:@selector(topMostAlert)];

Answer (score 0):

are you using `wkwebview` or `uiwebview`?if `wkwebview`,you can do `alertmessage` dealing by using `webview:runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage:` in `UIdelegate` ,this method can be also used if you are using `UIWebview` , but you need to add a new category,

for example:in my `viewcontroller.h`

```
@interface UIWebView(ViewController)
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)sender runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage:(NSString *)message initiatedByFrame:( id *)frame;
@end
```

and then in my `viewcontroller.m`

```
@implementation UIWebView(ViewController)
-(void)webView:(UIWebView *)sender runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage:(NSString *)message initiatedByFrame:(__autoreleasing id *)frame
{
   //do something about message
}
@end
```

and then i think you can choose what shall be alerted.

Comment: thanks humphry. i mean the alert is IOS's system alert.for example,"low battery" alert and "the request time out" alert.these alert were displayed by system.can i get them and display them?

Comment: oh,I think I got you , you mean alerts like that System tells you that the app is trying to get your location, contact and soon?These are apple's privacy policies and can't be avoided. But these shall only show once if you don't re-install your app. For webview, every site will show these alerts once if you do store caches local.Sorry I don't know how to solve your quz, Or you have a way out , tell me please.

Comment: thank you humphry.as humphry said,the location alert will show only once,but "the request timed out" alert will show once more. so,i hope i can display all alert.but ,very difficulty. My app will run in a tratin station where have no staff.so when a alert is showed ,it will not be allowed.i will find another way.thanks.